# Assembly x64 function parameters in rax instead of rdi

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, calling-convention

I read that we Must to use special registers to pass function arguments in Assembly
For example,

- > in windows x86 registers are:
  >   eax,ebx,ecx,edx
- > in windows x86_64 registers are:
  >   rcx, rdx, R8, R9
- > in linux x86 registers are:
  >   eax,ebx,ecx,edx
- > in linux x86_64 registers are:
  >   rdi,rsi,rdx,rcx, R8, R9

now i have a question about these registers .... are we forced to use these register for own functions too ?? for example if i create a function in Assembly, am i forced to use rdi,rsi and ... in linux ? or i just can use rax,rbx too ? (for my own functions not OS functions)

Comment: No, for your own functions you can use whatever you like. PS: you mixed up the system calls with the user space calling convention.

Comment: @Jester Not entirely; if you go through the PLT, the PLT stub will trash `r11` for example.

Comment: In theory, your assembler routine can use whatever registers it wants for parameters.  In practice, there's the question of how you are going to call that routine.  Compilers (c, c++, etc) typically follow the OS standard, and generate code that follows that convention.  Trying to convince them to use custom calling conventions is challenging and risky.

Comment: Related: an answer on [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165020) says "Choose your calling convention to put args where you want them." (if you're maximally optimizing an asm function that's only called from other asm functions).  e.g. you can return a boolean condition in ZF or CF if that's convenient, instead of a register.  And you can return more than one thing.  (e.g. `strcmp` or `memcmp` that returns the position of the first difference, as well as +/0/- compare status).

Comment: None of the stupid limitations of C or standard ABIs apply for internal helper functions.

Comment: thx all ..... very useful information ...